# Discrete minimization with constraints in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I've tried many ways but I could not find a way to efficiently minimize a function in python (preferable in sympy) of the form

Min f(x,y,z)
s.to 
g(x,y,z)>k

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Examples of what you've tried so far would help.

Comment: I donot know any optimization methods in python. So given two three variable function f and g I've defined 3 for loops like for x in range(), for y and for z and checked whether g(x,y,z)>k if so I defined a variable m representing the minimum and updated m continuously.

Comment: @LaurIvan If you know a manual or something let me know because the manual of sympy seems not enough to understand to solve these problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to minimize a function with discrete variable values in scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864474/how-to-minimize-a-function-with-discrete-variable-values-in-scipy)