# Scipy minimize: how to restrict x only to 0 and 1?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize a function with multiple parameters and constraints with *Scipy.optimize.minimize*:

```
def f(x):
    return -1*(0.9*x[0] + 0.8*x[1] + 0.85*x[2])*(0.95*x[3] + 0.8*x[4] + 0.7*x[5])*(0.98*x[6] + 0.94*x[7])

x0 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

cons=({'type': 'eq',
   'fun': lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 1},
  {'type': 'eq',
   'fun': lambda x: x[3] + x[4] + x[5] - 1},
  {'type': 'eq',
   'fun': lambda x: x[6] + x[7] - 1},
  {'type': 'ineq',
   'fun': lambda x: -1*(3*x[0] + x[1] + 2*x[2] + 3*x[3] + 2*x[4] + x[5] + 3*x[6] + 2*x[7] - 6)})
```

How do I tell python that x[i] can be only 0 and 1?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864474/how-to-minimize-a-function-with-discrete-variable-values-in-scipy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you could add equality constraints:

```
x[i] * (x[i]-1) = 0
```

In practice that does not work very well as this adds a nasty non-convexity to the model. It looks you have a non-linear objective and linear constraints and binary variables, so that would indicate we need to look at a MINLP (Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming) solver. Such solvers are readily available (e.g. [Bonmin](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin), [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne), [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron), [Antigone](http://helios.princeton.edu/ANTIGONE/)).

However there is something we can do. We can expand your objective, and write

```
maximize 0.9*0.95*0.98*x[0]*x[3]*x[6] + 0.9*0.95*0.94*x[0]*x[3]*x[7] + ...
```

or

```
maximize c1*(x[0]*x[3]*x[6]) + c2*(x[0]*x[3]*x[7]) + ...
```

These products like `x[0]*x[3]*x[6]` where all the x[i] are 0-1 or binary variables can be linearized as follows:

```
maximize c1*y1 + c2*y2 + ....
y1 <= x[0]
y1 <= x[3]
y1 <= x[6]
y2 <= x[0]
y2 <= x[3]
y2 <= x[7]
...
y1,y2,... binary variables
```

If we want we can make `y1,y2,...` continuous variables between 0 and 1. They will be automatically zero or one. More details are [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/reformulate-minlp-to-mip.html).

What we have now is a linear objective and linear constraints and binary variables `x[i], y[j]`. This can be solved with MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) solvers which are readily available. Very good ones are [Cplex](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/) and [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/), but there are also public domain ones such as [CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) and [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/). Many of them have Python bindings.